# StructureMap with Multiple global asax files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I am working on a project with multiple MVC projects within it. I want to use StructureMap, but I am not sure how I can (or if it is even possible) to define an IOC container that can be reused by two global.asax files (one for each project). I do not want to have to define two IoC containers for each. Can this be done any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from your question that the configuration is the same, you could put your registration in a common registry:

```
public class CommonRegistry : Registry
{
    public CommonRegistry()
    {
        // configuration here
    }
}
```

Then just initialize it in each application:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.AddRegistry<CommonRegistry>();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> (or if it is even possible)

No, that's not possible. The DI container stores objects in memory. Memory is per AppDomain. AppDomain is per application. Application is per Global.asax. So 2 Global.asax => 2 ASP.NET applications => 2 AppDomains => 2 different and unrelated memory regions. You could of course put your DI container configuration in a class library that will be reused by both ASP.NET applications.